# Annotate image on canvas with text

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with an image on it. When the user clicks on the canvas , I can find the x and y coordinates of the click. Now, i want to open a text box where the user can type something and write the result on top of the image. any ideas?

Comment: Something like this http://legndry.com/memebuilder/? See the source for details, the code is a bit long to be posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways I can think of doing this.  Probably the simplest would be moving a temporary text input (`<input type="text" />`) over the canvas, having the user type in that, and then when they are done, write the text to the canvas with [`fillText()`](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#text).  I would personally keep the text in the input fields for as long as possible, so that the user can go back and edit the fields.